# Using Windows metro icons in Websites

Tags: azure-web-app-service

i Want To Use Segoe MDL2 Assets font In My Website But I can't Get icons in Other Platforms Than windows Can You Provide Me the link to download font

Answer (score 2):

Against the licensing agreement.  I'd suggestion you move to another font.  I did some digging and can't find any documentation to the contrary.  Sorry.

Licensing Microsoft Fonts
Q. What can I do with the fonts supplied with Microsoft products? 
A. The fonts are governed by the same restrictions as the products they are supplied with. **You are not allowed to copy, redistribute or reverse engineer the font files.** For full details see the license agreement supplied with the product.

More info on font redistribution at http://www.microsoft.com/typography/RedistributionFAQ.mspx .